# Overlapping Images when making site Responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to convert a website I made into a responsive website. My website layout currently looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDk6p/

Except that the images overlap the way they do on the fiddle only when I re-size my browser to test what my page would look like on a smartphone. The only elements that are responsive are the two images in the middle (200x150) and the text below it. I'm trying to convert my website so that when I re-size the browser, everything, including the two images on the far right turns into a 1 columns site, matching the above element's width like so:

```
Enter text Here:
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

****************
*  Image       *
* **************             
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

****************
*  Image       *
****************
cccccccccccccccc
cccccccccccccccc
cccccccccccccccc

**Hello World**
ddddddddddddddd
ddddddddddddddd

***************
*  Image      *
*             *
*             *
***************

***************
*             *
*  Image      *
*             *

***************
```

I have this media query in my css code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){

    .events{

    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    line-height: 200%;


}

.events p{
    background-color: #d8b5a3;
    margin: 0 5%; 
    font-family: 'Chivo';
    color: #ffffff;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.events .events-plugin{
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    left: 10%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}


.container .picture{

    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
}
```

But it won't work, the images on the far right overlap. How can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing the HARD way, but here is what you want, on a simpler way:

http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/ZDk6p/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="col-main">
       <div class="img">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="flower">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
       </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SIDE BAR -->
    <div class="col-side">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/251x281" alt="events">
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
   border:1px solid blue;
}
.row:before, .row:after {
content: " ";
display: table;
clear:both;
}
.col-main {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid green;
    float:left;
    width:48%;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.col-side {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    width:48%;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
     .col-side,
     .col-main {
         width:100%;
     }
}
```

Work with this HTML structure (div):

```
<container>
<row>
<column1></column1>
<column2></column2>
</row>
</container>
```

*The first column will always be on top.

But you really should think in use a GRID SYSTEM for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you right, but try to put both of the images in a div, with a width of 100%, so it covers the full width of the page, and it cannot overlap. That worked fine with me.

Comment: This should be a comment not a answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that, new in here.